# Controller properties displaying as [object Object] (when using coffeescript)

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I have a controller written in CoffeeScript as follows:

```
class App.SidebarController extends Ember.ObjectController
  namez: (->
    @get('name')
  ).property()
```

This however returns as `[object Object]` in my view when I call the `{{namez}}` tag.

I re-wrote the same controller in JavaScript and the property prints out to the template as expected:

```
App.SidebarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  namez: function() {
    return this.get('name');
  }.property()
});
```

Any ideas as to why the CoffeeScript version isn't returning the proper value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extends` keyword of Coffeescript does basic prototype based inheritance. Ember's extends is actually a much more sophisticated object system that provides getters and setters, computed properties among other things. The 2 are not equivalent.

The equivalent Coffeescript for Ember would be,

```
App.SidebarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  namez: (->
    @get('name')
  ).property()
```

Comment: Nice catch.  I suppose it was from habit of writing Backbone code.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice coffeescript features like the fat arrow (to bind method to the instance) don't work when not using "class ... extends ..". How to get this working?